# User Contact View at log-in

Tags: drupal, contact-view, urls

I would like users to see their own CiviCRM Contact View straight away at log-in. I could create a Drupal module to do this, but what if I want the solution to be CRM independent. Can it be done in CiviCRM itself?

Answer (score 2):

We have done this for Drupal in the past just with a Views Block on the /user page, or wherever they go when they log in.

There is a write up about such a View (to show the users Membership details) in this [blog](http://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/showing-user-their-membership-status-using-views-block)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in a way that's CMS independent, but for the sake of thoroughness for those who might see this later... if you want a Drupal Rules solution, see here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/8727/105

Comment: Allen, thanks for your thoroughness. A good temporal solution before I find the other one.